# vim - run :!commands in my .bashrc

Tags: bash, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases)
>   [Why doesn't my vim know my alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235543/why-doesnt-my-vim-know-my-alias)

say I set 
`alias kapow='grep'`
in my .bashrc, which I source after.

I open vim, type

`:!kapow "dude"`

but vim tries to run /bin/bash kapow, when I actually wanted it to run my alias.

How does one run commands from a bashrc inside of vim (without leaving to the :shell)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases) and [Why doesn't my vim know my alias?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235543/why-doesnt-my-vim-know-my-alias)

Answer (score 9):

The [vim manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html) says this about `:!`

> On Unix the command normally runs in a non-interactive shell.  If you want an interactive shell to be used (to use aliases) set 'shellcmdflag' to "-ic".