# Executing Bash functions from within Vim - how can I do it?

Tags: bash, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases)

I have the following function in my **~/.bashrc** file (on my Ubunut box)

```
# convert tex to pdf, no bib 
function t2p {
    latex $1 && latex $1 && dvips $1 -o $1.ps && ps2pdf $1.ps && rm -f $1.dvi }

# convert tex to pdf, with bib 
function tb2p {
    latex $1 && bibtex $1 && latex $1 && latex $1 && dvips $1 -o $1.ps && ps2pdf $1.ps && rm -f $1.dvi }
```

For example, to convert a tex file **f.tex** to a pdf file and bibtex it in the right order, I call **tb2p f**. This works very well if I'm in a Bash terminal. However, to get to the Bash prompt from within Vim I actually have to execute the command **:sh** first.

To simplify the above procedure I tried to execute the functions **t2p** and **tb2p** inside Vim by **:!t2p f**. Vim then tells me that it cannot find the function **t2p**. I did some Googling and read that I should put these functions into the file **/etc/bash.bashrc** to make them visible to Vim. Unfortunately, this didn't work in my case. Vim still doesn't know about the function.

At the end of the day I would like to be able to call my functions from within Vim by using a keyboard shortcut. My questions are therefore as follows:

1. How can I let Vim know about **~/.bashrc** functions?
2. How do I setup a keyboard shortcut in **~/.vimrc** for a function in **~/.bashrc**?

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: That answer solved my problem! Will do some more Googling on my 2nd question. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Considered installing `rubber` which is an automated compilation system? `rubber -d main` will compile to a PDF `main.tex` and all dependencies and autodetect needs for bibliography or other compilation steps…

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9014154/1040358

Comment: It's funny this answer appear top of my Google search. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody provided the obvious answer as in the following example.
    function the_function { echo "Some output" ; }; declare -x -f the_function;
Now try run vim and use command ":r!the_function" to verify functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `:!bash -c t2p` in Vim. If your alias is limited to interactive shells also add the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 3):

`Vim` runs `bash` commands with the `-c` argument, which makes the shell non-interactive and non-login, and that bypasses reading the startup files.

You can override this with an environment variable.

From *man bash*:

```
   When  bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV
   in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to
   read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
   but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the file name.
```

Alternatively, vim itself can be asked to run command shells as login shells. From *`vim :help shell`* we get the following:

```
                    On Unix the command normally runs in a non-interactive
                    shell.  If you want an interactive shell to be used
                    (to use aliases) set 'shellcmdflag' to "-ic".
                    For Win32 also see |:!start|.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `set shell=bash\ --login` to your .vimrc.

To convert the current file, type `:!tb2p %`, the `%` will be expanded by Vim for you when executing the script.

Once it's working, you can add a mapping to make the whole process even faster:

```
nnoremap <F12> :!tb2p %<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your functions in a separate file and put that file in a folder 
in your PATH environment variable.
In my case my personal functions that I would use go to ~/bin

In your case for t2p:

create a file t2p in ~/bin with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# convert tex to pdf, no bib 
latex $1 && latex $1 && dvips $1 -o $1.ps && ps2pdf $1.ps && rm -f $1.dvi
```

then make the file executable:

```
> chmod +x t2p
```

make sure ~/bin is in your path, by putting the following in your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```