# Make Vim see RVM ubuntu

Tags: ruby, vim, ubuntu, rvm, bash

How can I set vim to see my ruby rvm install on ubuntu. rvm is installed and ruby returns from a terminal.

```
renshaw@renshaw-TravelMate-5740G:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

in vimrc I have set this.

```
set autowrite
set makeprg=ruby\ %
```

However when running make it cannot find ruby /bin/bash .

```
/bin/bash: ruby: command not found
```

Is there a way to make vim see this?

Edit:
In my bashrc this s the line I have for rvm.

```
if [[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8946710/900873). You need to add

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
```

to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: make sure you read [bash login](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq#shell_login) there are few gotchas in using ~/.bashrc