# Auto-rsync when saving file on VIM not working because rsync prompts password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, rsync

I'm configuring VIM to execute a `rsync` after saving a file, synchronizing my server with my dev laptop. It doesn't work because rsync prompts for my password, even if I've already set up a public key login. How to fix this?

Comment: `I'm configuring VIM` ... Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @hek2mgl :nnoremap <expr> <D-s> ':w!<cr>' . ':!rsync -r -e ssh ~/Folder/* user@my_ssh_server.com:~/Folder/ &<cr>' . ':!osascript ~/applescripts/chromereload.scpt &<cr>'

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ssh`-connection with `rsync`, you can always set up a passwordless connection for it. `[Here][1]` are [some](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=238672) nice tutorials. It can be done on windows too, via PuTTY, PLink, Pageant, etc. Read the docs.

Comment: I've already done that, I don't need a password to SSH login on my server, yet it asks some times when I try to rsync.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using vim for this, how about using [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)? It ships with most modern Linux distributions and will sync any changes, not just those you do in vim.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly define which `ssh-key` you are to use with `ssh -i`:

- `:nnoremap <expr> <D-s> ':w!<cr>' . ':!rsync -r -e ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ~/Folder/* user@my_ssh_server.com:~/Folder/ &<cr>' . ':!osascript ~/applescripts/chromereload.scpt &<cr>'`

Or you could you try to set your shell variable to interactive, i.e. use `~/.bashrc`++ (`man bash`). Not really sure if it has any effect.

- `:set shell=/bin/bash\ -i`

And/or define an alias in your `~/.bashrc` if needed. Maybe combine it with whatever `chromereload.scpt` does.

- `alias vimsync='rsync -r -e ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa ~/Folder/* user@my_ssh_server.com:~/Folder/'`

More information:
[vim -- not recognizing aliases when in interactive mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841116/vim-not-recognizing-aliases-when-in-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but it should work:

Put this into your ~/.ssh/config file:
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%n:%p
ControlPersist 300
KeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 60

Create the directory ~/.ssh/cm_socket and ssh into the server from another terminal. Now when you ssh into the server again it should use the same socket and no password is required, so your rsync command should work without password.