# Create custom Vim command to run function in bash profile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

Is it possible for me to create a Vim command that will execute a function in my bash profile?

In my bash profile, I have a function that uploads a file via webdav to a remote location. The function uses [duck.sh](https://duck.sh/) to accomplish this.

I would like to be able to edit a file in Vim, write updates to the file by typing `:w + enter`, and then run a custom command to execute my duck.sh function without closing the file.

Is this possible?  Here's the function I would like to execute:

```
upload() {
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
                echo "No file or directory submitted"
        else
                DIR=`pwd`
                if [ "$DIR" = "$WEBDAV_LOCAL_DIR" ]; then
                        duck -u $WEBDAV_USERNAME -p $WEBDAV_PASSWORD --upload $WEBDAV_URL/$1 $1 --existing overwrite
                else
                        echo "You must be in the following directory to use this function: $WEBDAV_LOCAL_DIR"
                fi
        fi
}
```

In order to work properly, the function will need to be passed the path to the file currently being edited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing Bash functions from within Vim - how can I do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162809/executing-bash-functions-from-within-vim-how-can-i-do-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use autocommands for this.

```
autocmd BufWrite .bash_profile silent! !bash -c upload
```

This will run every time  a file called `.bash_profile` is written.  You can remove the `!silent` if you don't want to silence the output.  You can read about some of these commands in these help topics:

```
:help :autocmd
:help autocmd-events-abc
:help :silent
:help :!
```