# vim: how to call alias through the ':!' directive?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commands executed from vim are not recognizing bash command aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases)

I've made an alias called "cache": alias cache="[shell command]"

Using vim, I'd like to call this alias through the ':!' directive, but I just can call "standard" commands like 'date' and so on?

How is it possible to make vim use my shell aliases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the suggested answer in the possible duplicate question didn't work for me. I currently use the following:

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ -i
```

It works fine.

Comment: For ZSH see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055613/zshell-aliases-like-gst-inside-vim

Comment: This does _not_ work for me.  Typing `!gcc --version` runs the command but then _suspends_ vim (_not_ subshell) and shows `[1]+ Stopped    vim`.  Just like using Ctrl-Z in other programs, typing `fg` gets you back to vim. … bash v4.1.2 … vim 7.4 … `shellcmdflag=-c` … `shell=/bin/bash\ -i`