# How to make VIM shell to call the consistent Python version with default shell

Tags: python, linux, unix, vim, editor

I have the following Python version callable like this from default 
shell outside VIM:

```
[pdubois@mymachine]$ which python
alias python='python2.7'
    /usr/bin/python2.7
[pdubois@mymachine]$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:13:15)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However calling it from within VIM shell, I get the different version

```
:!python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Jan 28 2011, 13:47:39)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

:!which python
/opt/otherpath/bin/python
```

How can I make VIM shell use the Python version like the default shell?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/commands-executed-from-vim-are-not-recognizing-bash-command-aliases) may be some helpful information.

Comment: Vim usually doesn't see your aliases. Can you compare the values of `$PATH` in and outside of Vim? And tell us what's the value of `'shell'` and `'shellcmdflag'` in Vim?