# How to set :!python3 to :!python in vim?

Tags: vim

To run a script using python3+ in vim (having Python2.7 as default), you need to type:

```
:!python3 <filename.py>
```

Technically, how do you run it with Python3+ with just:

```
:!python <filename.py>
```

An alias perhaps, just to shorten it.

Comment: You ca n use aliases, read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4642855/1005215

Comment: How about just symlink `/usr/local/bin/py` to `/usr/bin/python3` ;)

Comment: Also this is really not a Python question

Answer (score 2):

```
cnoremap !py !python3<Space>
```

This would substitute `!py` with `!python3` anywhere on the command line.

It is perhaps better than using `cnoremap py python3<Space>` as `!py` would not be as common as possibility of `py` on the command line

Also, you might notice `vim` waiting a few moments whenever you type `!` on the command line. You can continue typing regardless

Comment: 'cnoremap' can do the trick. But I find the link in the comments section the most useful in my case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a lot of python consider using map instead of remapping names of applications in vim only. Using map will probably save you a few key strokes and it will make what's happening more explicit. ctrl+shift+p seems like a good option. Of course, you'll change that to whatever works better in your own flow.

```
  " ctrl+shift+p to execute script with python3
  map <C-S-p> :!python3<Space>
```