# Calling a function from an alias in VIM results in ' syntax error near unexpected token `('?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I have an alias `alias new='misc.sh new'` that works fine in the shell. The script misc.sh has a few functions one is named 'new'. When the alias is called from vim `:! new arg` I get this syntax error:

```sh
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This is the first function in the script misc.sh, the syntax error points to this function. I don't think the problem is this function though.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

updatem(){ #both
#update all python modules
echo 'Outdated packages are'
pip3 list --outdated
for p in $(pip3 list -o --format freeze); do pip3 install -U ${p%%=*}; done
}
OUT=$(date +%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)

tags(){ #both
echo 'Another function'
}

new(){
echo 'This is my function'
}
```

I have tried this and it does not work:

```sh
new(){ misc.sh new; }
```

I don't know why it works fine in the command line but not in vim.

Comment: Is there a reason you reuse `new` so much? It probably will still work, but makes it confusing to understand and now to debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make .bashrc aliases available within a vim shell command? (:!...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642822/how-to-make-bashrc-aliases-available-within-a-vim-shell-command)

Comment: @wxz Even if I change 'new' to 'foobar' or whatever else it does not work. I can access the alias in vim or any alias in vim like ```ll```, that's not the problem. The problem is I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: Can you include the lines in your `misc.sh` file up to where the syntax error is?

Comment: @wxz updatem(){ #both
#update all python modules
echo 'Outdated packages are'
pip3 list --outdated
for p in $(pip3 list -o --format freeze); do pip3 install -U ${p%%=*}; done
}

Comment: @wxz I added to the question, much easier to read.

Comment: Do you have a shebang in the `misc.sh` file or is `updatem()` the first line in the file?

Comment: @wxz I have ```#!/usr/bin/env bash``` and I have ```shopt -s expand_aliases``` in ~/.bash_aliases which makes aliases work and I have in my vimrc ```let $BASH_ENV= "~/.bash_aliases"``` I already changed the bang to ```#!/bin/bash```.

Comment: Can you add all that to your post exactly as it is in your `.sh` file? There's a chance a typo happening before your function is causing this weird error. Sorry for all the requests

Comment: @wxz That's fine no problem, I understand these are hard to troubleshoot when there are so many factors involved. I added it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230853/discussion-between-wxz-and-ritchie).

Comment: @wxz How about I make you a repo and you can clone it into a new account ? Will take me a while to do this but would be much easier for you and me.

Comment: I created a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230853/discussion-between-wxz-and-ritchie), let's talk there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with OP, we found that in several places, OP had repeated, conflicting names. For instance, in one place `alias new` was used in `.bash_aliases` and separately a function `new()` was defined in a bash script.

The solution was to rename the aliases from the functions to avoid conflicts.